# GitHub - Create expandable text in Issues

Tags: github, formatting

I've looked at https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/ and https://help.github.com/articles/writing-on-github/ but didn't find any feature allowing to create expandable text. I'd like to add some code to the issue, but don't want to make it to take a lot of place. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I asked GitHub support and they said that this is not currently possible

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with html `details` tag:

[Example of using with markdown.](https://gist.github.com/pierrejoubert73/902cc94d79424356a8d20be2b382e1ab)

Here is a small example:

````
<details>
<summary>My dart code</summary>

```dart
void myFun() {}
```
</details>
````

Will turn into this:

Collapsed:

[image]

Expanded:

[image]